# Finding the pdf of $V=\max{\{X,Y\}}$ where $X∼\text{unif}(0,2)$ and $f_Y(y) = \frac{y}{2}I_{(0,2)}(y)$

Tags: probability, proof-verification, probability-distributions

> Give the pdf of $V=$ max${\{X,Y}\}$, where $X$ and $Y$ are
>   independent random variables, with $X∼\text{unif}(0,2)$ and $Y$ has pdf
>
> $$f_Y(y) = \frac{y}{2}I_{(0,2)}(y)$$

$$\begin{align*}
F_{V}(v) 
&= P(V\leq v) \\\\
&= P(\max{\{X,Y\}} \leq v) \\\\
&= P(X \leq v, Y \leq v) \\\\
&\overset{\mathrm{ind}}{=} P(X \leq v) \cdot P(Y \leq v) \\\\
&= F_X(v) \cdot F_Y(v) \\\\
&= \frac{v}{2} \cdot \int_0^v \frac{y}{2}dy \\\\
&= \frac{v}{2} \cdot \frac{v^2}{4} \\\\
&= \frac{v^3}{8}I_{(0,2)} \\\
\end{align*}$$

So I have that the pdf of $V$ is

$$f_V(v) = \frac{3}{8}v^2 I_{(0,2)}(v)$$

Is this a valid solution?

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: Thanks. Is it frowned upon to post questions if you think you did it correctly but just want verification?

Comment: I don't think so, perfectly valid use of the resource. Especially when you format is so nicely and make it readable :)

Comment: More simply, $$f_{\max(X,Y)}=f_XF_Y+F_Xf_Y$$